# Altering a error message when it is JSON

Tags: discussion, editing

I added some markdown to the question: [Azure Machine Learning Classic web service gives the error too many open devices](https://serverfault.com/questions/1051270/azure-machine-learning-classic-web-service-gives-the-error-too-many-open-devices)

While I consider it benefits from syntax highlight, now it displays a horizontal scrollbar.

This error message is a JSON. It is minified:

```
{"error":{"code":"LibraryExecutionError","message":"Module execution encountered an internal library error.","details":[{"code":"FailedToEvaluateRScript","target":"Execute R Script Piped (RPackage)","message":"The following error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in png(file = \"aaca47f6beb44537892250e8969f6100rViz%03d.png\", bg = \"transparent\") : \n too many open devices\n"}]}}
```

It will be essentially the same JSON if I add some CRs to make it "pretty printed", but easier to read:

```
{
    "error":{
        "code":"LibraryExecutionError",
        "message":"Module execution encountered an internal library error.",
        "details":[
            {
                "code":"FailedToEvaluateRScript",
                "target":"Execute R Script Piped (RPackage)",
                "message":"The following error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in png(file = \"aaca47f6beb44537892250e8969f6100rViz%03d.png\", bg = \"transparent\") : \n too many open devices\n"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it is also an error message, and I think error messages must be left unedited as much as possible.

It is acceptable to edit error messages in a JSON (or other structured) this way to make reading easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the two forms are semantically identical, and you note that the original has been modified for readability, I don't think there's any major problem.